# React to events of Android apps

Tags: android, events

I am looking for a way to create some sort of "wrapper app" that reacts to events of certain apps, e.g. an sms being received, or some other app notifying the user with a toast.

Is there a best practice?

I have read about `Context Wrapper`, but am yet uncertain, whether this would be the correct approach.

Is what I am trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can be triggered on system events (phone call, notifications, etc.) via Broadcast Intents : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html . It can be also used for receiving events from other apps but **only if** developers have implemented and allow this behavior.